# How to export DGraph database in a docker container (Windows)

Tags: docker, dgraph

I hope I was terse but specific enough at the title:
**What I am trying to do**

- To export/backup the entire DGraph database.

Answer (score 3):

- execute `docker exec -it <container id> curl localhost:8080/admin/export`
- ascertain that the `export` folder is found under `/dgraph`
- cp from the `dgraph server` like so: `docker cp <container id>:/dgraph/export .`
- locate your database export at your `pwd`
- `rm -rf` the `export` folder in the container.

references:
 - https://discuss.dgraph.io/t/unable-to-run-admin-export-on-server-via-putty/1748/9